Do tangent vectors of a manifold extend into the ambient space?
Imagine the unit sphere. Attach a plane $W$ tangent to the north pole $p= (0,0,1)$. $W$ should include all vectors tangent to $p$. Now if we choose any vector with $p$ as it's tail and some other point in $W$ as it's tip, then no matter how small this vector is, that point must belong in the ambient space because, by assumption of being tangent, the tangent plane only touches at one point, so all other points must be in the ambient space.
Doesn't this mean tangent vectors must exist in the ambient space and not just on the manifold?

The vector is the arrow, which is an algebraic object that lives in $T_pM$. The point corresponding to its tip if we extended it from $p$ is meaningless

Yes. With standard definitions in differential geometry, the tangent space of a submanifold is naturally identified with thr subspace of tangent space of ambient manifold.

I think OP is saying that tangent vectors of the submanifold are points on the ambient manifold ($\mathbb{R}^n$), which is not the case

Another way to frame your question is "If I am standing at some coordinate on Earth and walk 3 mph north, is my velocity in outer space? If I walk even faster, is my velocity even further out in outer space?" Velocity vectors don't tell us where anything is, just the direction we're traveling in

I interpreted OP's question as asking whether, for other point $q$ in $W$, the vector $pq$ is a tangent vector of $\mathbb{R}^n$. @whpowell96 is correct that points and tangent vectors should be distinguished.

@whpowell96 that was exactly what i was trying to say.

I thought a point can't have direction and magnitude. I thought it's just a location. So the idea of having a vector to me implied it needed two points. And to have a second point and still be tangent seems impossible because how can both points lie on the submanifold and have the vector still be tangent -- i thought tangency implied touching at one point...which meant to me the other point must lie in the ambient space

But @whpowell96 's comment seems to suggest that its like velocity whereby, it's like the "potential" to go to another point and not actually realized. So consequently, two points are not needed because the vector itself doesn't correspond to  points on the submanifold but instead to a vector of the rate of change of the curve at that point

The question seems to presuppose that having the notion of tangent vectors requires a manifold to be embedded in something like a vector space, and that's not true. There are various intrinsic definitions of a tangent vector at a point $x$ on a manifold $M$, one of which is as a derivation at $x$, namely, an ($\Bbb R$-)linear map $D : C^\infty(M) \to C^\infty (M)$ satisfying the Leibniz identity
$$D(fg) = D(f) g(x) + f(x) D(g) .$$
So, "sticking out" of a manifold (and into some ambient space) is really just an artifact of how tangent vectors are often visualized. Even when there is an ambient space, without more structure there's no notion of which point is "at the end" of a tangent vector.
In the case that $\Bbb V$ is a real vector space and $M \stackrel\iota\hookrightarrow \Bbb V$ is a submanifold, we can identify a tangent vector $X \in T_x M$ with the vector $T_x \iota \cdot X \in T_{\iota(x)} \Bbb V$, and so under the canonical vector space isomorphism $\Phi : T_{\iota(x)} \Bbb V \cong \Bbb V$, we can identify $X$ with the arrow (vector)

with tail at $\iota(x)$ and
head at $\iota(x) + \Phi(T_x \iota \cdot X)$,

the latter of which need not be in the image of $\iota$.
If we endow $\Bbb V$ with a translation-invariant metric $g$, then the location of the head is just $$\exp_g T_x\iota \cdot X ,$$ where $\exp_g$ is the Riemannian exponential map determined by $g$. So, we can use the same formula to generalize our notion of "head of a vector" to the case that our manifold $M \stackrel\iota\hookrightarrow (N, g)$ is a submanifold of a Riemannian manifold. In general $\exp_g T_x \iota \cdot X$ will not be an element of $M$ (more precisely, in the image of $\iota$), but it will be if $(M, \iota^* g)$ (i.e., $M$ equipped with the pullback metric) is a totally geodesic submanifold of $(N, g)$.
